# Maven calling maven plugin goal from command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Can you tell me how to call maven surefire in command line with the following configuration ?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Custom tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>target/generated/classes/normalCase/</classesDirectory>
                <reportsDirectory>target/generated/reports/normalCase/</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When surefire is defined like this in my pom.xml and I execute the phase test, it work exactly how i want it to work : it tries to run my tests on the classes located in target/generated/classes/normalCase.

So I tried this command line:

```
mvn surefire:test -DclassesDirectory="target/generated/classes/normalCase/"
```

But no, it keep checking the classes in the default value directory which is "target/classes".

So how can I achieve this in command line ?

Answer (score 1):

To recap the situation you have. You are generating multiple version of your source code during the build, each of those version ends up in a separate folder under `target`. For each of those versions, you would like to execute your unit tests with the `maven-surefire-plugin`. Let's consider the base directory to be `target/generated/classes`. That means you have multiple subdirectories `target/generated/classes/version1`, `target/generated/classes/version2`... for each version.

A possible solution would be to use the [`iterator-maven-plugin`](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/index.html) to iterate over [all subdirectories of a folder](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/iterator-folder.html) and invoke the `maven-surefire-plugin` from all those subdirectories. The variable `@item@` holds the current item.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>iterate</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>iterator</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <folder>target/generated/classes</folder>
                <pluginExecutors>
                    <pluginExecutor>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.19.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <configuration>
                            <classesDirectory>target/generated/classes/@item@</classesDirectory>
                            <reportsDirectory>target/generated/reports/@item@</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </pluginExecutor>
                </pluginExecutors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It seems that the loop in well executed. The @item@ capture the good value because the report is created at the right place. The tests are run, but they don't seem to see my classes. I have the error : NoClassDefFoundError in ClassATest ClassATest.testMethodA(). I don't really understand, because if it knows that one of my tests contains the method "ClassATest.testMethodA()" it means that it has been able to read the ClassATest.class, and therefore it perfectly found its definition... I don't know. Thank you very much anyway, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @Vanesbush Hmm that's weird. Would it be possible for you to make a simple project (on GitHub for example) with which I could reproduce?